# Bluetooth keyboard returns weird resutls with UITextFieldDelegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` that has 14 `UITableViewCells` visible at any one time. each `UITableViewCell` has a `UITextField`, When I focus onto the first `UITextField` all of the `UITextField` delegates work as expected. However if I then press the tab key on the Bluetooth keyboard things go crazy and I do not know how to stop the crazy form happening.

this is the code I currently have to show you how mental things go.

```
//////////// START /////////////
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Should Begin");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Did Begin");
}


/////////// END ///////////////
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Should End");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Did End");
}
```

so as you can see I am using 4 of the `UItextField` delegate methods just to show you what happens when I press the tab key on the Bluetooth keyboard....

this is the out put when tab key is pressed once.. and only once.

First the first textfield is selected manually.

```
Should Begin
Did Begin
```

Then I press the tab key

```
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should Begin
Should End
Did End
Did Begin
```

for some reason the tab key goes through every single `UITextfield` available then jumps back up to the next `UITextfield` and starts on it... I have no idea why or how this is happening I would like some help resolving this issue... any idea on how to stop this?

Comment: You are testing your iOS app on simulator and using your bluetooth keyboard to enter data into text fields and text views. Why do you care about tab key of your keyboard?? It wont effect your app as there is no tab key in iOS soft keyboard..

Comment: No, I am testing it on a device that has a bluetooth keyboard attached. The person I am writing the application for will want to use a bluetooth keyboard so I am trying to control what the tab key dose so it dosnt break my app.